# How return works in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def sum_it(n,y):
if n ==0:
    return y 
else:
    return sum_it(n-1,n+y)
```

required output for sum_it(3,4)i.e. (3+2+1)+4 must be 10
but obtained output is 5

Please how the return really works ?

Comment: Why must the required output for `sum_it(3,4)` be `10`? All you're doing is returning `1 + y`, so I would **expect** it to return `5`... A summing function would return `n + y` and have no need for recursion. And `return` works no differently in recursion; it stops re-calling `sum_it` due to the `if` conditional being entered instead of the `else` conditional.

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to sum like (3+2+1) + 4, this code will works.

```
def sum_it(n,y):
    if( n == 1): 
        return y + 1
    else:         
        return(n + sum_it(n-1,y))
```

For example, `sum_it(3,4)` works like below

```
sum_it(3,4) returns 3 + sum_it(2,4)
sum_it(2,4) returns 2 + sum_it(1,4)
sum_it(1,4) returns 1 + 4
```

It means

```
sum_it(3,4) returns 3 + 2 + 1 + 4
```

Comment: i want to add y to the series i.e. 3+2+1 + 4

Comment: Ok, I added "n + " to the return argument as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Altough unclear, it seems like what you need when calling `sum_it(n,y)` is the sum of natural numbers from 1 to `n` plus `y`.

This initial sum is also known as "nth" triangular number.

[image: Triangular Number]

If that's the case, you actually don't need recursion:

```
def sum_it(n,y):
    return (n*(n+1))//2 + y
```

---

If recursion is a must:

```
def sum_it(n,y):
    if (n > 1):
        return n + sum_it(n-1,y)
    return n + y
```

Feel free to ask if any doubt remains.